# What is meant by a quantum factoring for entangled states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

The definition of an entangled state $|\Psi\rangle$ is that it CANNOT be factored into
$$|\Psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle_1\otimes|\phi\rangle_2$$
I am kind of confused on what is meant by a quantum factoring.  For example, my professor gave us an exercise to do ourselves:
$$|\Psi\rangle_{12}=\frac12(|+_z\rangle_1|+_z\rangle_2+|+_z\rangle_1|
-_z\rangle_2+|-_z\rangle_1|+_z\rangle_2+|-_z\rangle_1|-_z\rangle_2)$$
I believe that this is not entangled, because it would be the product of states with total j=1 and total j=0.  Is that correct, and how could I show this mathematically?

Comment: Start with a general product of two single particle states and see if you can choose $a,b,c,d$ such that $\left|\Psi_{12}\right\rangle = \left(a\left|+\right\rangle_1 + b\left|-\rangle_1\right)\otimes(c\left|+\right\rangle_2 + d\left|-\right\rangle_2\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat this factoring problem just like you would factor an algebraic expression. In this case, your expression is equivalent to $AX + AY + BX + BY$, so factor it similarly:

$$\begin{aligned}
|\Psi\rangle_{12}&=\frac12(|+_z\rangle_1|+_z\rangle_2+|+_z\rangle_1|
-_z\rangle_2+|-_z\rangle_1|+_z\rangle_2+|-_z\rangle_1|-_z\rangle_2) \\
&= \frac12 \left(\left(|+_z\rangle_1\right)\left(|+_z\rangle_2+|-_z\rangle_2\right)+\left(|-_z\rangle_1\right)\left(|+_z\rangle_2+|-_z\rangle_2\right)\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Try to finish factoring this expression yourself, and if you need more guidance, feel free to ask in the comments.